# Pass variable into url parameter php

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a variable from a form to another php file to create an xml file.

```
   <?php

        $sentxt = $_POST['text']; //this comes from the form php 

         $params = array(

            'answer_url' => 'to_xml.php?msg="$sentxt"', 

        );
     $response = $p->make_xml($params);
     echo "$sentxt";

    ?>
```

Whenever I try to run this I run into a problem

The xml file keeps outputting "$sentxt" instead of the string passed to the $sentxt via the php form post.
The echo "$sentxt"; displays the right string has been passed through properly, but the string is never passed into the array.

Comment: PHP strings 101: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variables

Comment: @Marc is right, should remove the quotes 
echo $sentxt;

Comment: I've tried  'to_xml.php?msg=$sentxt',  and it doesn't work either

Comment: Quotes at the echo don't matter. In the array assignment the value needs to be concatenated or processed with double quotes. It is `"to_xml.php?msg=$sentxt"` or `'to_xml.php?msg=' . $sentxt`

Comment: Ok @MarcB I found the error thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `'` with `"` for string interpolation.

```
<?php
    $sentxt = $_POST['text']; //this comes from the form php 

    $params = array(
        'answer_url' => "to_xml.php?msg=$sentxt", 
    );
    $response = $p->make_xml($params);
    echo $sentxt;
?>
```